# Encoding url parameters, needs to be short

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to encode the parameters I'm sending to the controller. My controller and the parameters look like this: `Anket/716026/3`. What I did to encode it is combine the two parameters as `7160263` (always get standard length). Then use these encode and decode methods:

```
function encode($id) {
        $id_str = (string) $id;
        $offset = rand(0, 9);
        $encoded = chr(79 + $offset);
        for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($id_str); $i < $len; ++$i) {
          $encoded .= chr(65 + $id_str[$i] + $offset);
        }
        return $encoded;
      }

function decode($encoded) {
        $offset = ord($encoded[0]) - 79;
        $encoded = substr($encoded, 1);
        for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($encoded); $i < $len; ++$i) {
          $encoded[$i] = ord($encoded[$i]) - $offset - 65;
        }
        return (int) $encoded;
}
```

The encoded string looks like this: TMGLFHLI. Which is exactly what I want it to look like: short and easy to type. But since it's randomized, I get a random encoded string each time. So it could also look like these; XQKPJLPM, OHBGACGD, SLFKEGKH etc.

This doesn't affect the decoding process as you can see. But the produced link is for a survey link and a user would be distributing these links to people. Should I encode them once and store them in the database to maintain the same encoded string to avoid confusion? Or should I just leave it as is? If you know a better encoding method, please let me know.

Comment: Why not just create a random token for each survey when they are created which you store in the database together with the survey? Then you don't need to encode/decode stuff but just query on that token to fetch it from the database.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I did consider it but here's my reasoning. The surveys aren't stored at first. Only the result calculations are, after the form is sent. I get the necessary data from other tables to construct the form. I thought I could find a fitting and fast encoding algorithm to do this on the spot. But I'm now considering a table just for storing the two parameters and the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**
You can use `chr()` to convert the number to `character` and `ord()` to convert character to `integer`.

```
function encode($id) {
    $array = str_split($id);
    $encoded = '';
    foreach($array as $val){
        // 65 = A
        // 65 + 1 = B
        $encoded .= chr($val + 65);
    }

    return $encoded;
}

function decode($encoded) {
    $array = str_split($encoded);
    $decoded = '';

    foreach($array as $val){
        // Convert to ASCII value
        $decoded .= ord($val) - 65;
    }

    return (int) $decoded;
}
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!
$str = '7160264';
$encoded = encode($str);
$decoded = decode($encoded);
echo 'Encoded: ' . $encoded . "\n";
echo 'Decoded: ' . $decoded;
```

**Output:**

```
Encoded: HBGACGE
Decoded: 7160264
```

The output will always be the same without using the random number offset. The random letter only is from A to J only.

**OLD ANSWER** You can use `base64_encode` and `base64_decode`.

**Example:**

```
$str = '7160264';
// Remove the ==
$encoded = rtrim(base64_encode("7160264"), '=');

echo 'Encoded: ' . $encoded . "\n";
// Concat == when decoding again.
echo 'Decoded: ' . base64_decode($encoded .'==');
```

**Output:**

```
Encoded: NzE2MDI2NA
Decoded: 7160264
```

Comment: This was the first thing I used but it has letters, numbers and both uppercase and lowercase letters. My peers didn't approve it. So, I tried using this method instead.

Comment: Updated version is quite similar to mine, except for the randomness. I should use this instead, thank you. One question, I read that tinyurl and things alike have a collision probability. Would you recommend shortening the result further with those methods, or is it safer to use it this way?

Comment: I'm not familiar how tinyurl works. I'm not sure if my answer is the safer. You can still further short this by converting **two numbers** instead of **one** to `char` and limit it to `Z` only.

Answer (score 0):

To make your life more easy you can use CI encryption library.
First you must set your encryption key in application/config/config.php:

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'YOUR KEY';
```

Then use this:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Encrypt extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();          
        $this->load->library('encryption');
    }

    public function encrypt_string($some_string){
       return $this->encryption->encrypt($some_string);
    }

    public function decrypt_string($some_string){
       return $this->encryption->decrypt($some_string) == $password);
    }

    public function test(){
       $data = $this->encrypt_string('encrypt me');
       var_dump($data);
       var_dump($this->decrypt_string($data));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function encryptit($string)
{
    $en_string = openssl_encrypt($string, AES-128-ECB, SECRET);
    $en_string = base64_encode($en_string);
    return $en_string;
}

function decryptit($string)
{
    $de_string = base64_decode($string);
    $de_string = openssl_decrypt($de_string, AES-128-ECB, SECRET);
    return $de_string;
}
```